# Firebase Remote Config crashing when getting value. Not key value coding-compliant

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm following the documentation for setting up Firebase for iOS.

```
remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
remoteConfig.setDefaults(fromPlist: "FirebaseRemoteConfigDefaults")
let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
remoteConfig.configSettings = settings
print("Remote Config Response:\(self.remoteConfig.value(forKey: "OnboardingGroup"))")
```

Then it crashes when trying to get the value saying **"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key OnboardingGroup.'"**

Not really sure where I might be going wrong. Would appreciate any help with this.

Here is my FirebaseRemoteConfigDefaults.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>OnboardingGroup</key>
    <string>group-1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but it also crashes when setting the value manually.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6625

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use configValue(for: key) instead of value(for: key). Leaving this here in case anybody else runs into this.